# Tag <style> can not appear inside <style>, only <item>

Tags: android, xml, styles

```
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">

    <style name="bigText">
        <item name="android:textSize">50sp</item>
    </style>

</style>
```

Hey everyone,
I keep getting this error! As you can see from on top, this is what i'm using in my style.xml sheet. Is there something i'm missing? I've even followed Google's documentation and i'm still getting that issue.
Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to create your own custom style to use with text views you need to define it outside the style headers of the main theme. Like:

```
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">

</style>

<style name="BigTextTheme">
        <item name="android:textSize">50sp</item>
</style>
```

Then in your layout resource

```
<TextView>

...blah
style=@style/BigTextTheme
</TextView>
```